# Compiling PCL for use with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, kinect, point-clouds

I'm trying to **compile PCL for use with OpenCV** on Ubuntu (64 bit).

I'm following instructions on official [website](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html).

when I do a "**make**", I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/pcl_example_extract_clusters_normals
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcl_visualization
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/pcl_example_extract_clusters_normals] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/segmentation/CMakeFiles/pcl_example_extract_clusters_normals.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by editing cmake file. Visualization module was not being built for some reason. I customized the cmake file using command `ccmake` to make it build visualization module also.

Comment: Can you show what did you edit exactly and how? (I know this was a long time ago...)

Answer (score 1):

I also had to edit the cmake file to build visualization, but then I also found I needed to install libvtk5-dev, otherwise the visualization module would be automatically turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cmake-gui` and enable `BUILD_visualisation`